# GitHub Pages giving 404 after custom domain (ReactJS + Vite + Hostgator)

Tags: reactjs, vite, github-pages

I uploaded a personal project into GitHub Pages and it was working properly until I tried to put a custom domain in it.

After the configuration of the DNS that apparently its working fine, the GitHub side can't properly display the website by the new domain.

First thing that I made sure it was the CNAME file in the Public Folder on my project:
[CNAME file with the single line of code into my GitHub page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myOpY.png)

Then in my package.json file I typed my custom domain name on "homepage":
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4w6w.png)

And finally in vite.config.js, I changed the "base" to "/":
[vite.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkRxv.png)

On GitHub Pages, on the custom domain part I typed "*my-domain*.com.br"
and I had the green for DNS config working properly.

Just for the sake of more info, the domain provider I am using is Hostgator and this is the configuration I made on the DNS:

A:
[image]

AAAA:
[image]

and the CNAME with www.*my-domain*.com.br pointing to *my-github*.github.io.

So, anyone have any idea of what might be wrong on my configs?

I tried a lot of different configs into package.json and vite.configs files, putting the original **base** **url** as /repo-name and the **homepage** as https://*my-github*.github.io.

Depending on the configs, sometimes I got a white screen with the header html file with the right meta tags of my project but with no content besides this, but I don't know which way is closer to solve my problem...